# May HTTP server send a 400 response without waiting for the request body?

Tags: http

When my client is making a POST request containing a non-empty body to an HTTP server (IIS 7.0) the server responds with 400 without waiting for the whole request body being fully transmitted.

Can anyone point out where the HTTP standard describes this situation: premature response without waiting for the whole request being transmitted?

UPDATE:
in fact the server waits for the full message, the problem was in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it "should" be reading it.  [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-31) states:

> The presence of a message-body in a request is signaled by the
> inclusion of a Content-Length or Transfer-Encoding header field in the
> request's message-headers.

...and...

> A server SHOULD read and forward a message-body on any request

Perhaps something else is wrong, such as routing.  Maybe post some code.

Comment: you were right, it does read all message, turned out it was a bug in my code, duh... thanks for the reply anyway